# How to reload parent window after detecting query parameter in child window?

Tags: javascript

So I open a popup like this;

```
let windowObjectReference = null;
var url = "{% url 'login' %}";
const openSignInWindow = (url) => {
const strWindowFeatures =
'toolbar=no, menubar=no, width=600, height=700, top=100, left=100';
windowObjectReference = window.open(url, name, strWindowFeatures);
}
```

Then I go through some OAuth process(in the popup) which ends up at my redirect URI with a query param called "code" ; now I want to detect the availability of this param in the child window; then reload parent window with the current URL in the child window;

URL looks like this "http://127.0.0.1:8000/spotify/callback/?code=xxxxxxx"

So I went about it like this using JS in the redirect page like;

```
 function url_checker(){
     <p>Please wait...</p>;
     return window.opener.document.location.href = window.location.href;
   };

if (window.location.toString().includes("code")){
    url_checker();
}
```

But this isnt working, in my console I see `127.0.0.1/:27 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'` ; and the parent window doesn't get reloaded.

Comment: First of all, please go read [ask]. _“But this isnt working”_ gives us no useful information at all. Give us a _proper_ problem description, including what error messages you get, if any.

Comment: @CBroe provided an edit.

Comment: What’s the point of using a popup in the first place, if you are then reloading your parent window with the result URL of the login process anyway? Might as well _redirect_ to the login URL in the existing window, and spare yourself all this hassle.

Comment: Well of course you get that error - `<p>Please wait...</p>;` is HTML, and not JavaScript, and you can not just insert the former into the latter, and expect that to still be valid JS syntax then.

Comment: When I look at various websites that implement `OAuth`, a login page is opened in a popup and after authorization is done, parent page is reloaded. That is what I was trying to implement @CBroe